# CKEditor toolbar isnt properly adapting to the screen size on mobile, some of the toolbar items to be hidden and requiring horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

My project use Nuxtjs and Vue2, it is a web for smart phone. I 've imported ckeditor but when i see the docs examples, the toolbar not make horizontal scroll.

This is template

```
<template>
        <v-flex :class="col" class="ck-editor-box">
            <v-row>
                <v-col :class="colInput" class="pt-0">
                    <client-only placeholder="loading...">
                        <ckeditor-nuxt v-model="ckeditorData" :config="editorConfig" />
                    </client-only>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-flex>
</template>
```

This is script

```
<script>

export default {
    name: 'CKEditorField',
    components: {
        'ckeditor-nuxt': () => { if (process.client) { return import('@blowstack/ckeditor-nuxt') } },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            // editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorData: '',
            editorConfig: {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'undo', 'redo',
                        '|', 'heading',
                        '|', 'alignment',
                        '|', 'fontsize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', 'bold', 'italic', 
                        '|', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'todoList', 'outdent', 'indent',
                        '|', 'link', 'uploadImage', 'code',
                    ],
                    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: false
                },
                removeButtons: ['FontSize', 'PageBreak'],
                removePlugins: ['Title'],
                placeholder: this.placeholder,
                simpleUpload: {
                    uploadUrl: 'path_to_image_controller', // image path api
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'optional_token'
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Some item have dropdown list such as 'numberedlist' will make horizontal scroll when it is placed near border of the screen (idk how to describe :))) )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeVkA.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need more config toolbar:  **shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true**

For example:

```js
let editorConfig =  {
        removePlugins: ['Title'],
        toolbar: {
          shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).